# Best practice for implementing a rating system

Tags: computers, rank

I wish to implement a rating system In order to match players with similar strength. My domain is several trick taking card games of either 2 players or 4 players, and the results are Win/Lose/Draw.
My question is, what is the **best practice for a rating system for trick taking card games?**
Or what are the considerations that I need in order to decide which rating system is best fit for my needs?

**My needs are**: Improving the experience of players by matching players with similar strength.  It does not need to be extremely accurate.

a quick search discovered three systems:

1. ELO - [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system), [Explanation](https://mattmazzola.medium.com/implementing-the-elo-rating-system-a085f178e065)
2. Glicko - [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glicko_rating_system)
3. Glicko 2 - [Glickman site](http://www.glicko.net/glicko.html), [Paper by Glickman](http://www.glicko.net/glicko/glicko2.pdf)

A nice comparison between [ELO and Glicko in this paper by Michalis Kaloumenos](https://www.englishchess.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Elo_vs_Glicko.pdf)

---

I Think BGA [made a good job implementing ELO ranking](https://boardgamearena.com/page/ranking), so it is probably good enough for me as well.

Comment: This sounds like a very broad question, more of an invitation to a discussion. Could you try to narrow it down? For example, clarify what exactly "your needs" are?

Comment: @Hackworth, Added "my needs" section.  Please tell me if that makes a better question

Comment: Is it better belongs to boardgames.meta ?  (discussion, support, and feature requests for this site)

Comment: Still not sure what the actual question is, your edit basically seems to repeat what you already wrote. You also already found a comparison of rating systems, what question does it not answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends. There is a ton of scientific research on the topic of ranking all kinds of things. It would probably take a long time to get up to speed on that. But if I get you right, you instead just want something that's easy to implement and works good-enough. That's a lot easier then.

If the ranking task is synchronous, e.g. tournaments where everyone is present at the same time, I'd look into the [Swiss system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss-system_tournament) or similar. In Go in Europe, we use a variant called [McMahon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McMahon_system_tournament) that combines rating points with tournament performance that has been working exceptionally well for this purpose.

If the ranking is asynchronous, probably points-based, anything like ELO, Glicko, etc should work. It's not clear to me from the question which further requirements you have in this regard. If there are none, I would just go with the one that appeals to you most and/or is the easiest to implement.